# Spark 2.2 Scala DataFrame select from string array, catching errors

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to SparkSQL/Scala and I'm struggling with a couple seemingly simple tasks.

I'm trying to build some dynamic SQL from a Scala String Array.  I'm trying to re-type some columns in my DataFrame, but I won't know exactly which I need to retype until runtime where I can see the set of columns in the DataFrame.  So I'm trying to doing this:

```
val cols = df.columns
val typedCols = cols.map( c => getTypedColumn(c) )
df.select( ...)  or df.selectExpr(...) // how to invoke this with vals from my string array??
```

typedCols will end up being an array of strings with values like this:

```
["a", "cast(b as int) b", "c"]
```

Do I need to create a big comma delimited string first from that array?

So, assuming this will work, I'd invoke that select statement, and it would transform my DataFrame to a new DataFrame with my desired types.  But some of those records in the DataFrame will have errors, and will fail the attempted re-typing.

How would I get a DataFrame result with all the good records that passed the typing and then throw all the bad records in some kind of error bucket?  Would I need to do a validation pass first before attempting the DataFrame select?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use variadic arguments:

```
val df = Seq(("a", "1", "c"), ("foo", "bar", "baz")).toDF("a", "b", "c")
val typedCols = Array("a", "cast(b as int) b", "c")
df.selectExpr(typedCols: _*).show

+---+----+---+
|  a|   b|  c|
+---+----+---+
|  a|   1|  c|
|foo|null|baz|
+---+----+---+
```

but personally I prefer columns:

```
val typedCols = Array($"a", $"b" cast "int", $"c")
df.select(typedCols: _*).show
```

> How would I get a DataFrame result with all the good records that passed the typing and then throw all the bad records in some kind of error bucket?

Data that failed to `cast` is `NULL`. To find good records use `na.drop`:

```
val result = df.selectExpr(typedCols: _*)
val good = result.na.drop()
```

To find bad check if any is `NULL`

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val bad = result.where(result.columns.map(col(_).isNull).reduce(_ || _))
```

To get unmatched data:

- If `typedCols` are `Seq[Column]` you can

  ```
  df.where(typedCols.map(_.isNull).reduce(_ || _))
  ```
- If `typedCols` are `Seq[String]` you can:

  ```
  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

  df.where(typedCols.map(expr(_).isNull).reduce(_ || _))
  ```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is good but missing another simple solution:

```
val columns = Array("name", "age")
val df2 = df.select(columns.map(col): _*)
```