# Spark DataFrame - distinguish between a record having a missing column vs a bad value

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

This question is related to this thread:
[Spark 2.2 Scala DataFrame select from string array, catching errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47700885/spark-2-2-scala-dataframe-select-from-string-array-catching-errors)

I need to distinguish between records missing columns (which is not an error in my use case) and records having garbage values that don't work for the column type.

After I do my selectExpr, both of these situations appear as null in the resulting DataFrame.  I'm looking for a fast way to include the records missing columns in with the good results, while throwing the records having garbage values in a bad bucket.  The bad would include things like an int field having the empty string as a value, or "abc".

For example, say I have DataFrame like this:
Col A - string,
Col B - int,
Col C - string,

```
A    B    C
"x", "",  ""  - Error, bad value for B
"",  null,""  - Good, missing value for B
"",  "a", ""  - Bad, bad value for B
"x", "1", "x" - Good, normal case
```

----- edit -----

Showing code creating the dataframes.  Data comes in as json, all fields are quoted so it initially thinks everything is a string.  I need to type several of the fields to int, boolean, etc.  See link at top for full details.

```
 val cols = dfLower.columns
 val typedCols = cols.map( c => getTypeStmtForCol(c, qradarType) )
 val result = dfLower.selectExpr(typedCols: _*)

 // This puts both records with missing columns and bad values in bad.
 // Need way to distinguish between those 2 cases.     
 val bad = dfLower.where(typedCols.map(expr(_).isNull).reduce(_ || _))
 val good = result.na.drop()
```

---- edit 2 ----

I think I may have an idea.  If I could count the number of nulls in each record before and after, then only those records with more nulls after the select should go in error.  Unsure how to implement that...

Comment: Not clear what's a "missing value" - A DataFrame has a _single_ schema, all records (Rows) share the same schema so they all have *the same* columns. What's your input - is it a CSV? Something else? Maybe this would be clear if you show the code that _creates_ the DataFrame.

Comment: See edit above.  Looking at DF, the missing values in columns are already null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sort of quick and dirty but create a udf that tests your conditions and returns a status based on the outcome of the conditions.

```
def checkIntData=udf((columnData: String) => {
  var status = "GOOD"
  try{
    columnData.toInt
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception => {
      if(columnData == null) {
        // Do nothing. This is fine
      } else if(columnData.length == 0) {
        status = "ERROR"
      } else {
        status = "BAD"
      }
    }
  }
  status
})

val seqData = Seq(("x","","","0"),("",null,"","3"),("","a","","z"),("x","1","x",""))
val df = seqData.toDF("col1","col2","col3","col4")
val colsToCheck = df.select("col2","col4").columns
var newdf = df
// Iterate over the columns you want to check inside the dataframe. Each checked column will add a new status column to newdf
colsToCheck.map{column =>
  newdf = newdf.withColumn(column+"Status", checkIntData(newdf(column)))
}
newdf.show()
```

This will return the following:

```
+----+----+----+----+----------+----------+
|col1|col2|col3|col4|col2Status|col4Status|
+----+----+----+----+----------+----------+
|   x|    |    |   0|     ERROR|      GOOD|
|    |null|    |   3|      GOOD|      GOOD|
|    |   a|    |    |       BAD|     ERROR|
|   x|   1|   x|   z|      GOOD|       BAD|
+----+----+----+----+----------+----------+
```

You can then create your error bucket by filtering based on the status column.

Columns 1 through 3 are from your example. I added column 4 to show how to apply this to multiple columns without having to write `.withColumn()` a hundred times. I achieved this by creating an array of columns `colsToCheck` and then iterating over to apply the udf to all the selected columns.

NOTE! Since I'll probably be yelled at for doing so I want to let you know that using try/catch as flow control is considered an anti-pattern (aka bad programming). [Read more to find out why.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why)

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I ended up doing.  I had a validateRecord() function that returned true or false depending on if it found any garbage data in fields I was typing, but was ok with nulls.  Then I filtered on true and false to create a good and bad dataframe.  It was kind of annoying that I had to filter twice, couldn't see a way to split dataframe based on results of my function.